# IIS hosted website went down. How to investigate

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

I have a data driven web site running on Windows 2012/IIS 7.5 environment. It went down for 2 minutes last night. Once in a while it does that.

Our firewall monitors in the website and i can see 500 responses for a minute like below. And then after 2 minutes it is up and producing 200.

```
2016-01-05 04:11:41 172.16.10.56 GET /service/status/ - 443 - 172.16.10.2 Barracuda+Load+Balancer+Server+Monitor - 500 0 64 81531
2016-01-05 04:11:50 172.16.10.56 GET /service/status/ - 443 - 172.16.10.2 Barracuda+Load+Balancer+Server+Monitor - 500 0 64 60531
2016-01-05 04:12:20 172.16.10.56 GET /service/status/ - 443 - 172.16.10.2 Barracuda+Load+Balancer+Server+Monitor - 500 0 64 60531
```

I don't see anything on the event viewer.

How would you investigate these kind of issues that shows up with no obvious reasons?

Answer (score 0):

To investigate this type of issue in the future you should enable logging of Application Pool Recycling. Based on the symptoms that you described it is highly probable that the core problem is the Application Pool being stopped or otherwise unavailable during a short time frame.

This assumption is based on the fact that there are no System or Application Event Logs indicating that the web process crashed. Depending on the type of web application running and the App pool settings an Application Pool recycle may take quite some time (seconds). To mitigate this in the future you should modify the 'Advanced Settings' for the Application Pool(s) to use 'overlapped recycling'. This will insure that there is an active web process to handle any requests during these Application Pool recycles. Alternatively, you can modify the Recycling settings in such a way that Recycles simply do not occur. However, this is not ideal and could lead to other issues.

Comment: But Usually when I reset IIS (technically an application pool recycling), the IIS logs creates header and starts logging again. So I would see the IIS logs header in the middle of the text file. It is not the case in here. Isn't it safe to assume application pool did not recycle at this moment?

Comment: Functionally, Application Pool Recycling is not the same as restarting IIS. Restarting IIS does stop the Application Pool temporarily, but Recycling the Application Pool does not stop IIS. As a result, Application Pool recycling would not interrupt or effect the IIS logs in any meaningful way other than the observed 500 http codes being written.

Comment: Another question - 1740 mins what my iis's recycle time is set to (default). Is there any way to know if this is what caused the issue? Even if it is the issue it won't bring it down for 2 mins. Can it?

Comment: Enabling the Application Pool Logging will allow you to determine if this is what is occurring. Alternatively, you can look at the frequency of this problem and determine whether it is roughly ~29 hours (1740 minutes) apart. I have observed that the downtime of the Application Pool can sometimes be excessively long as you have seen. However, this can be resolved by changing the settings I mentioned above (Overlapped Recycle). Hope this helps!